# I am unable to undo more than one step back when using a particular Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

### Beginning of... I added this after posting the question below

For example, entering "ulianababenko" into either A2 or B2 would cause both A2 and B2 to display "ulianababenko". Yes. A2 and B2 would display the same text.

However, A2 would link to behance.net/ulianababenko whereas B2 would link to behance.net/ulianababenko/moodboards. In other words, A2 would link to the first URL; and B2 would link to the second URL.

### End of... I added this after posting the question below

Normally in an ordinary Google Sheet, when I press `Ctrl + z` repeatedly, I am able to undo many steps back.

However, in this Google Sheet **-->** [Behance.net- sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlB-MDUveSJyPK5Pw5GABaAn-ZwBTcE-4DQlCIdmWPI/edit#gid=2046852903), when I change, for example, A3 from test1 to Ben and then change A4 from test2 to Jacob, and then press `Ctrl + z` once I am **able** to undo Jacob (in A4). However, when I press `Ctrl + z` a second time, I am **unable** to undo Ben (in A3).

In such a case, of course, I would like to be able to undo Ben (in A3).

The Google sheet linked to above contains the following Apps Script....

```
function onEdit(e){
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
    myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
    }
}
}

function myFunction(sheet,range,value){
if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}
}
```

#### I tried the following but it caused the original scrip to stop working properly

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
    }
  }
}


function myFunction(sheet,range,value){
if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}
}


function onEdit(e){
  if (!e.oldValue.includes("https://www.behance.net")) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
      for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
        myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### I tried the following on 29 January 2022 but it caused the original scrip to stop working properly

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (!e.oldValue.includes("https://www.behance.net")) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
      for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
        myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(sheet,range,value){
if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}
}
```

Comment: The visible values are the same. Yes. But they link to different URLs.

Comment: Please help me solve the problem I asked.

Comment: Currently when I type "foo" into either A2 or B2 visually "foo" is displayed in both A2 and B2. Maybe you are asking, "Huh? What? Why?" See, A2 and B2 link to different URLs. A2 links to www.behance.net/foo/ whereas B2 links to www.behance.net/foo/moodboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

An `onEdit` function that changes the value that was just edited doesn't work well with undoing changes.

#### Explanation:

For every edit your users make, there's an additional edit made by your script: turning the new values to rich text values.

Therefore, in order to undo each manual edit, you should undo the action twice (one for the manual edit and one for the script edit). But, each time you undo an action via `ctrl + z`, that "undo" counts as a further edit and your script gets triggered again, making in its turn an additional change to the spreadsheet.

That is, every time you try to undo a change, the script makes an additional change. So, if you want to undo multiple actions, you'll have to press `ctrl + z` many times and fast enough so as to not give the script time to change the value again.

#### Workaround:

As a workaround for your specific case, I'd suggest checking whether the old value (pre-edit) contains the string `https://www.behance.net` (using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) property `e.oldValue`). If I understand your workflow correctly, that will mean the script is triggering due to an "undo" action, and so it should not make an additional edit.

```
function onEdit(e){
  try {
    if (!e.oldValue.includes("https://www.behance.net")) {
      update(e);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    update(e);
  }

}

function update(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(sheet,range,value){
if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}
}
```

Comment: I added the script above to... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlB-MDUveSJyPK5Pw5GABaAn-ZwBTcE-4DQlCIdmWPI/edit#gid=2046852903 but it didn't work. Therefore, I removed it.

Comment: In https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlB-MDUveSJyPK5Pw5GABaAn-ZwBTcE-4DQlCIdmWPI/edit#gid=2046852903... entering "ulianababenko" into either A2 or B2 would cause both A2 and B2 to display "ulianababenko". However, A2 would link to https://www.behance.net/ulianababenko whereas B2 would link to https://www.behance.net/ulianababenko/moodboards.

In other words, A2 would link to the first URL; and B2 would link to the second URL.

Comment: @ScootinOn `but it didn't work` can you clarify what this means? What were you getting instead? It did work for me when I tested it before posting it.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea if your script actually worked. I didn't test it at all. Why not? Because after I installed your script I tried entering data into column A and column B I noticed that the original script had stopped working.

Comment: @ScootinOn When you tested the script I posted, I hope you didn't overwrite `myFunction`. I didn't add that function to my script because no change is needed there, but the function should be in your script, since it's used by `onEdit`.

Comment: I edited my original question by appending the code I tried adding which failed. Please read the bottom part of my original question.

Comment: @ScootinOn You have to **replace** the `onEdit` in your original question with the `onEdit` in my answer, **not keeping both** (in any case, it doesn't make sense that the script stops working when you add both `onEdit`, but whatever).

Comment: I edited my original question by appending the code I tried adding which failed under the section entitled, "I tried the following on 29 January 2022 but it caused the original scrip to stop working properly"

Comment: @ScootinOn I noticed this was failing when the source cell was empty before editing it (since in that case, `e.oldValue` is undefined, and the function fails). Maybe that's the problem you were facing. I edited my code to handle that edge case (again, replace all your code with this one, don't keep duplicate functions).

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem. Now the Google Apps Script works properly although I do need to be sure to press Ctrl + z *rapidly* to undo, say, 5 or more steps back. In other words, if I press Ctrl + z *slowly* I am unable to undo, say, 5 or more steps back. But that's a trivial problem which I can easily overcome... if I remember.